# Error al actualizar un campo NULL en MySql

Tags: mysql, null

Tengo una tabla con valores en null que quiero actualizar para que todos sean 0 ,estoy haciendo esta instruccion

```
UPDATE pedido set cajas = 0 WHERE cajas IS NULL ;
```

donde "cajas" es el campo con valores en null, pero al realizar la consulta no afecta a nada , siendo que hay muchos campos con valores en null como pueden ver en la siguiente consulta [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en total hay 298 valores en null , pero al tratar de actualizar no hace nada, si alguien me pudiera indicar que podria estar mal se lo agradeceria

Comment: Hola, prueba con `UPDATE pedido set cajas = 0 WHERE isnull(cajas)`

Comment: Pues yo he probado tu consulta y es funcional en un ejemplo que hice, pudieras agregar detalles como el tipo de dato que usas para almacenar en dicha columna

Comment: @Aprendiz el tipo de datos es un int por pero como predeterminado metia null, lo cambie para que fuera 0 pero me tope con este problema

Comment: ¿Cómo guardas el valor `NULL` así o como cadena de texto así `"NULL"`?

Comment: @Aprendiz en el phpmyadmin estaba configurado como predeterminado null, no como una cadena de texto, de hecho creo que si fuera como cadena de texto mi consulta que puse en la imagen no funcionaria

Comment: Se me hace raro por que he replicado tu escenario y me funciona con `IS NULL`

Comment: Primero verifiquemos cuántos registros ya están en 0 y cuántos siguen en NULL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pedido WHERE cajas = 0; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pedido WHERE cajas IS NULL;
Otra cosa que hace falta es que muestres la definición de las columnas: DESCRIBE pedido;
Por último, postea también el resultado de ejecutar UPDATE pedido SET cajas = 0 WHERE cajas IS NULL; Así será más fácil encontrar el problema.

Comment: Podrias aplicar un count para ver si los registros son esos que mencionas?

Comment: Todavía hace falta es que muestres la definición de las columnas: `DESCRIBE pedido;` y el resultado de ejecutar `UPDATE pedido SET cajas = 0 WHERE cajas IS NULL;` . Así será más fácil encontrar el problema.